# Defeating Copperhead in Arkham Origins

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I defeated Copperhead in the steel mill, got the antidote, and went outside and told Alfred to send me samples of the gas...

My objective is still to defeat Copperhead. Where can I find her to finish my objective?

Answer (score 3):

You are suffering a bug. This should happen normally:

> You are supposed to defeat her once again

but for some people this does not trigger. [This person has the same issue as you](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=35033491). You should try to contact the official support team for this game as I am not sure how you could pass this checkpoint if it saved after the bug.